# If $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n \in\mathbb Z$. If $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is odd.

My proof by contradiction is as follows but I'm pretty sure its wrong any help would be welcome.

If $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is even.
If $n$ is odd $n = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.
$$n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^2 +2k) + 1.$$
Let $m = 2k^2 + 2k$. Then $n^2 = 2m$ so by definition $n^2$ is even but this is a contradiction because $n^2$ is odd.

Comment: You missed the $1$ in $n^2$ after substitution. $$n^2 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + \mathbf{1} = 2m + \mathbf{1}$$

Comment: you can use euclids lemma

Comment: I'd just like to point out that often times when you first try to prove something, your inclination will be to do it by contradiction if you don't know how to proceed. So usually what will happen in this case is you start proving the thing, eventually do prove it, and this contradicts your assumption that it was false. So your proof carries along a lot of needless baggage. This stops happening with practice. Nevertheless, what you've got looks pretty good, and the other answers explain what's going on just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need a proof by contradiction, and you've almost proved the result in your original post. For $n$ odd, i.e. $n = 2k +1$, we have $n^2 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1 = 2m + 1$ is odd, $m=2k^2 + 2k$.

Answer (score 1):

if $n$ is odd then $n(n-1)$ is even and so $n(n-1)+n$ is odd.

Comment: n(n-1) is always even too

Comment: yeah good point.

Comment: although its easier to prove it if we already know the parity of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for proof by contradiction here; but if you wish:

Since $n$ is odd, then $n = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.
Let's assume for the sake of contradiction that $n^{2}$ is even.
Then, $n^{2} = (2k + 1)^{2} = 4k^{2} + 4k + 1 = 4(k^{2} + 1) + 1,$ which is an odd number, contrary to our assumption that $n^{2}$ is even. Therefore, $n^{2}$ must be odd.

This is pretty much what you had up to the second to last line of your proof where you obtained your contradiction, and so, $n^{2}$ must be odd. (You don't want your last line.) Do you see why proving this directly would have been more expedient?